# HTTPGet then store in sqlite

Tags: android, json, sqlite, http-get

Need a little nudge here in the right direction.

I have an api that is returning the results I need to store in my androids sqlite db.

Just making sure I have a correct overview of what I need to do. Can someone put eyes on this and make sure I am about to go down the correct path?

On create
Check for a sqlite db (If exists do nothing)
Else
(create sqlitedb)

New async task
Connect to api

Do HTTPGet

Do HTTPPost which will return results that I will need to "Parse"?

Then store those in sqlite?

Comment: I see no issues in your logic.  What made you want to ask this question?  Do you have concerns that this won't work?

Comment: If you are using Android's `SQLiteOpenHelper` class (which you should), you don't need to worry about checking if the DB exists or not, and you don't need to create it yourself. Android will take care of that for you.

Comment: MrZander- I know very very little about JSON in android, so I wanted to make sure I am headed in the correct path before I start learning the http get post with and with out passing an argument and sqlite stuff.